# How to pass parameter that will be deserialize as json in WCF restful service?

Tags: c#, json, rest, wcf

The contract

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Filter/{paramName:paramValue}/"),  
 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string[] Filter(string paramNameAndparamValue);
```

The implementation

```
public string Filter(string paramNameAndparamValue)
{
     string[] tmp = paramNameAndparamValue.split(':');

     // do something ... 
}
```

Is there any why to pass this restful method a parameter that will be use as json object and avoid of using the `string.split`?

Comment: Mark the parameter as an array like `Filter(string[] paramNameAndparamValue)`? Note that your contract and your implementation differ in their return types.

Comment: and in this case - how i will pass the param on restful ? how to pass the 2 string ?

Comment: how to write the line [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Filter/{paramName:paramValue}/"),  
 if i will use string[]

Comment: Or, actually, just change your URI template to `"Filter/{paramName}:{paramValue}/"` and the signature to `string[] Filter(string paramName, string paramValue)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below

**Iservice.cs**

```
 [OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Filter/{paramName}/{paramValue}"),  
 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string[] Filter(string paramName,string paramValue);
```

**service .cs**

```
public string[] Filter(string paramName,string paramValue);
{
    //your code;
}
```